# Adminthtml failing to compile

Tags: magento-2.1, adminhtml, css, static-content, less-css

We have an ongoing issue with our `styles.less` file that prevents the css being generated for the `Magento 2.1.8` back end.

Whe i run the command

`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

It throws this error

```
Compilation from source: /microcloud/domains/operm2/domains/dev.website.co.uk/http/vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend/web/css/styles.less

Compilation from source:
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/css/styles.less
Unable to get content for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_Checkout/css/source/_module.less'
```

In the styles.less file it is failing to import any of the other `_module.less`.

We currently have around 20 imports in this file:

```
@import '../Magento_Checkout/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Ess_M2ePro/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_AdminNotification/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_AdvancedCheckout/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Backend/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Banner/css/source/_module.less';
@import '../Magento_Braintree/css/source/_module.less';
```

When i comment out the first import line:

```
@import '../Magento_Checkout/css/source/_module.less';
```

The error will then change to:

`adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Ess_M2ePro/css/source/_module.less`

has anyone encountered this error before? The file paths for the imports all contain the expected files, could this be an issue with permissions?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I am also having same issue. It started happening all of a sudden. We tried setting permissions but didn't help. Every time we used to delete app directory and pull it from our repo to make static content deploy work. Not sure what is the problem, we are still investigating the issue. Let us know if you get any solution.

Comment: Hi Kalyan. As a work around, we are copying the adminhtml styles.css from one of our backups directly into the pub/static folder. This might  be a quicker temporary work around for you.
I have found a number of people who have had this issue and then they say have fixed it without giving a solution. If I find a solution I will make sure to post it back here so any future people who have the problem can easily fix it.

Comment: out of curiosity, what are the contents of your styles.less file in the vendor directory?

Comment: We didn't even touch any less file, we added a custom CSS file for frontend changes.

Comment: did you over ride the existing theme?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74745/discussion-between-kalyan-chakravarthi-v-and-dwhalley).

Comment: any news on that? same issue here